# Select tag doesnt take (selector).HTML value in mobile ios

Tags: jquery, ios, select

Live demo: https://sas2.ru/jquery-ios-select.html

Select doesnt take HTML variable in mobile ios, with picker activated. All other browsers work fine.

```js
var numberselector = '<option value="0">0</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option>';
$('select.magicnumber').html(numberselector);
$("#selectednumber").keyup(
  function() {
    var input = $('#selectednumber').val();
    //$("#magicnumber option[value='"+input+"']").attr("selected", "selected");
    $("#magicnumber").val(input);
    $("#magicnumbercheck").html(input);
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="selectednumber" id="selectednumber" type="number" value="1" placeholder="Введите число" style=" width: 208px; ">
<select name="magicnumber" id="magicnumber" class="magicnumber" style="width:208px;">
</select>
<!--Следующий блок для проверки-->
<div id="magicnumbercheck"></div>
```

Comment: Use the `input` event instead of `keyup`

Answer (score 0):

i don't know, if it is exactly the right answer, but it worked for me

Before my js was in separate file, that started with

```
(function ($) {
"use strict";
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
```

Аfter i moved function inside html file in

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

It just started to work at IOS IPHONE as well.